# PayPal android sdk Sandbox Integration

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to integrate paypal in my android application,and i used paypal sdk2
for testing I used Paypal environment as Sandbox,but in the PaymentActivity page the sandbox button seems to be disabled

Here is my code for paypal configuration

```
     PaypalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration();
     config.environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX).clientId("myclientId");
```

On clicking on the Buy button i called the below function

```
private void buyFromPayPal() {
       PayPalPayment payPalPayment=new PayPalPayment(new    BigDecimal(1.75),"USD","Bike",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

And i am getting a out put screen like this[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not disabled, it is **indication of sandbox build**.

you can continue with your payment, real money will not be charged for that.

Once you use live mode api key and secret key, that sandbox text will be removed by `Paypal SDK`.